# Execution time of consecutive executeUpdate() SQL statements

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

How safe is it to use multiple consecutive executeUpdate() methods on SQL database?

Considering 2 statements:

```
st.executeUpdate("INSERT table SELECT col1,col2 FROM table WHERE ID=" +var_id);
st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM table WHERE ID=" +var_id);
```

How does they behave? Does the 2nd statement wait for the completion of 1st or should we check for the returned value (number of rows affected) and act accordingly with 2nd statement?

Comment: Depends on whether your connection is set to auto-commit. What JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: I guess that would depend on whether the method is asynchronous or not.  If it's returning a code (say, a straight integer, like 100 - 'Rows not found'), that means it's completed.  _Always_ check such codes.  Also, you're currently open to SQL Injection; use prepared statements.

Comment: If your connection has auto-commit on, it will commit each transaction and the above would be perfectly safe.  It should be safe even if you don't have auto-commit on, but you'd need to remember to manually commit or roll back.  If you want the first statement to roll back in case the second statement fails, then you'd want auto commit off.  Most JDBC drivers auto commit by default (at least I think JTDS does).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A call to `executeUpdate` is not asynchronous, so it will not return until after the statement has been executed on the server. In other words: these two statements will work and they will not interfere as they are executed one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that statement can execute multiple queries simultaneously being a *single* instance.

The second statement will wait until the first one is *completed and returns*.
The second statement will only be set with new query after the first one's completion.

This is also applicable in case of reading ResultSet.
Documentation says:

> > By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "single instance", but certainly a Statement object can execute multiple SQL statements within the same transaction.  You can use the addBatch and executeBatch methods to execute multiple statements in the same transaction.

Comment: executeUpdate doesn't return ResultSet. I'm just not sure whether the 2nd statement will be executed only after 1st is finished. It should, but I have a moment of doubt. Trying it now and getting NullPointerException.

Comment: Yes. I am aware about executeBatch and executeUpdate does not return a resultset. I don't think that OP is using add batch command. Resultset is just given as an example of similar operation with single statement object.

Comment: But `executeUpdate` does return an affected rows count, so it will need to wait for completion of a statement.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes. Even in batch updates next query in batch is executed after first one is completed, no matter it succeeded or failed. Refer to [*executeBatch*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch())

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether or not you have autocommit turned on for your database.

If you have autocommit turned on, the second statement will wait for the first statement to complete and commit before executing.

If you have autocommit turned off, the second statement will execute after the first statement, but no changes will be applied to the database until a commit.

Comment: This does not depend on autoCommit, in both cases a call to `execute`, `executeUpdate` etc will only return when the statement has been execute by the database.